# All Access to this object has been disabled when using carrierwave/fog to upload to aws s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I'm getting this error when I try to upload to s3. I checked to make sure my aws credentials were correct. Here's the error that i'm getting.

```

```
Excon::Errors:`:Forbidden: Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)
excon.error.response
  :body          => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AllAccessDisabled</Code><Message>All access to this object has been disabled</Message><RequestId></RequestId><HostId></HostId></Error>"
  :cookies       => [
  ]
  :headers       => {
    "Connection"       => "close"
    "Content-Type"     => "application/xml"
    "Date"             => "Fri, 13 May 2016 22:14:48 GMT"
    "Server"           => "AmazonS3"
    "x-amz-id-2"       => ""
    "x-amz-request-id" => ""
  }
  :host          => "s3.amazonaws.com"
  :local_address => "10.0.0.24"
  :local_port    => 57133
  :path          => "/uploads/script/file/1/Facebook-2006.jpg"
  :port          => 443
  :reason_phrase => "Forbidden"
  :remote_ip     => "54.231.114.148"
  :status        => 403
  :status_line   => "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n"
```

```

And this is how I configured carrierwave/fog
config/initializer/carrierwave.rb

`CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider: "AWS",
    aws_access_key_id: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
  }
  config.fog_directory = ENV["AWS_S3_BUCKET"]
end`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Idiot move.  I was setting the name of the bucket name wrong. I wrote ENV["AWS_S3_BUCKET"] instead of ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']. It was saying access denied probably because it was trying to access a bucket that doesn't exist or is the root of s3.

Comment: Super easy mistake to make, glad you were able to sort it out.

Comment: hahaha good thing there is an issue for this error. I have made the same mistake of wrong bucket name. The message should be more informative though.

Answer (score 0):

Does the bucket has public access permissions? and if it does you can try and set the AWS region of your bucket in the configuration of fog?

Comment: I gave permissions to 'everyone' for every action to test it out but it still gives the same error.  I also tried setting the region to us-east-1 since the bucket is under US Standard with no luck.

Comment: Ahhh I'm an idiot.  I was using the wrong name for my environment variable. I was saying ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'] rather than ENV['BUCKET_NAME_S3'].  Thanks for the help!